# Make magic links for meta work on meta

Tags: feature-request, magic-links

In a recent comment discussion, I noticed that there is no way to write a magic link for [meta.stackoverflow.com].  While other sites (say, [meta.workplace.se] ), allow you to specify the hotlink at any location (since you can always write them out 'long' style), it's not a big deal that [meta] doesn't work.

However, for trilogy sites (and really any site with a direct .com address), you can't do that.  Thus, it would be helpful to allow [meta] to automatically convert to [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com), even on said site (not just on the main site).

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see this as being worth the time to implement, even though I too would like it if the short/magic link `[meta]` expanded to [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), just like it does on the main site.

The thing is, is this really *that* useful? Using the short links `[so]` and `[main]` on Meta is convenient because it saves you the trouble of having to type out

```
[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com)
```

However, if you're *already* on Meta, what benefit do you gain from being able to use `[meta]` over simply typing out "Meta"? People don't need a link to Meta Stack Overflow here, they're already on it! Usually, when people talk about "Meta" here, they're usually referring to Meta Stack Overflow (MSO), and not [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) (MSE), so it's usually not something that's ambiguous.

Comment: I'm curious how much time you think this would take to implement?  I imagine they have a SQL table with two columns, "magicLinkText" and "magicLinkURL"...

Comment: @Joe I figured that if it really was that easy, then they would have already implemented it by now...but I could be wrong.

Comment: I assume that it, like many other FRQs, just didn't come to mind :)